# MongoDB nodejs updateOne always returning modifiedCount: 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I’m having an issue where I’m attempting to update my document and the change is not being reflected. I suspect MongoDB is finding that my value is somehow the same even though I’ve changed it

```
const User = require('./assets/models/User.js');
var message = user.messages;

//should be an empty array for right now, can be something like 
//['erin': [{ from: ‘erin’, to: ‘erin’, content: ‘test’ }]]
//in the future

if (!message[otherPerson]) message[otherPerson] = [];
await message[otherPerson].push(msg);
//where msg is a msg object
//pushes message into new index

//updates messages with new data
const test = await User.updateOne({ usertag: person }, {
$set: { messages: message }
});
console.log(await test);
```

I’ve tried multiple formats of updating such as

```
User.updateOne({ usertag: person }, {
messages
});
```

where the messages variable is called message in the earlier example
or

```
User.updateOne({ usertag: person }, {
$set: { messages }
});
```

and nothing seems to work
I will also mention that this is some rather old code that used to work pretty well. Has something changed in how MongoDB handles updates or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the _full_ response from the database?  Specifically is it showing that a document matched the filter?

Comment: yes, it is showing that a document matched the filter. modifiedCount: 0, matchedCount: 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new value to the `messages` array you should use `$push`:

```
const test = await User.updateOne({ usertag: person }, {
    $push: { messages: msg }
});
```

If you want to edit a specific `message` you should filter by its id and reference the specific array element (I'm assuming that `_id` is your identifier for `message` elements):

```
const test = await User.updateOne({ usertag: person, messages._id: msg._id }, {
    $set: { 
        messages.$.from: msg.from,
        messages.$.to: msg.to,
        messages.$.content: msg.content,
    }
});
```

Also, you should not `await` the `test` result since you already resolved the `Promise` awaiting the `updateOne`:

```
console.log(test);
```

Comment: That's not exactly how I did it but it led me to the right answer! Thanks! I am now using $push :)

Comment: OH AND YOU ALSO ANSWERED A QUESTION I WAS JUST ABOUT TO HAVE HAHAHA THANK YOU SO MUCH <3 I'd upvote you but I don't have enough rep :(